# Scalatest - how to create parallel test at runtime

Tags: scala, scalatest

running

```
package com.thron.qa.tests

import org.scalatest.{FunSuite, ParallelTestExecution}
import org.scalatest.concurrent.Eventually

class ParallelRuntimeTest extends FunSuite with Eventually with ParallelTestExecution{

  Vector.range(0,10).foreach(iteration => {
    test ("test number  n " + iteration.toString) {
      succeed
    }
  })

}
```

i obtain runtime test creation : iteration over the vector builds up to the tests and every single test has it success status as you can see in the Idea Ide

[image]

Now, i want to parallelize these test

normally i use .par to obtain parallelization of operations,
so the code becomes

```
Vector.range(0,10).par.foreach(iteration => {
    test ("test number  n " + iteration.toString) {
      succeed
    }
  })
```

but in this case,
i obtain this error :

> An exception or error caused a run to abort: Two threads attempted to
>   modify FunSuite's internal data, which should only be modified by the
>   thread that constructs the object. This likely means that a subclass
>   has allowed the this reference to escape during construction, and some
>   other thread attempted to invoke the "testsFor" or "test" methods on
>   the object before the first thread completed its construction. 
>   java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: Two threads attempted to
>   modify FunSuite's internal data, which should only be modified by the
>   thread that constructs the object. This likely means that a subclass
>   has allowed the this reference to escape during construction, and some
>   other thread attempted to invoke the "testsFor" or "test" methods on
>   the object before the first thread completed its construction.

how to create test at runtime and runs these in parallel way?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `test` command does not *run* any tests. It simply *registers* a test case, attaching a string name to it. It takes no resources, and is essentially instantaneous. Therefore, it is not necessary to register the test cases in parallel. As your error message shows, it's also not possible to register them in parallel anyway.

Create your tests sequentially, they will be run in parallel automatically:

```
import org.scalatest.{FunSuite, ParallelTestExecution}
import org.scalatest.concurrent.Eventually

class ParallelRuntimeTest 
extends FunSuite 
   with Eventually 
   with ParallelTestExecution {

  for (i <- (0 to 59)) {
    test ("test number  n " + i) {
      Thread.sleep(1000)
      succeed
    }
  }

}
```

If you test it, you will notice that it takes roughly 15 seconds instead of a minute (I think that's because the default number of threads used for tests is four, so 60 / 4 = 15).

Comment: True. my trouble was with the intellij idea ide, that will not execute test in parallel way. so i "forcing" the ide searching for a parallelism that sbt does by default. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As @Andrey Tyukin mentioned, By default sbt runs all tasks in parallel and within the same JVM as sbt itself. Because each test is mapped to a task, tests are also run in parallel by default.

We can turn off parallel execution of tests for multi-project builds as below.

```
parallelExecution in Test := false,
parallelExecution in IntegrationTest := false
```

It looks like there is issue in using ParallelTestExecution and "sbt test" -scalaTest 3.0.x (https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest/issues/898). However workaround for this issue is in Overriding Distributor.

```
class Example extends FunSpec with ParallelTestExecution with StressTest {
  describe("Example") {
    for (i <- 1 to poolSize) {
      it(s"test ${i} should run in parallel") {
        info(s"example ${i} start")
        Thread.sleep(5000)
        info(s"example ${i} end")
      }
    }
  }
}
```